# How to change border color and width of OutlineButton globally?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to change the border **color** and **width** of the `OutlineButton`, I know one way of doing this by directly mentioning it inline as below:

```
OutlineButton(
  child: Text('SIGN IN'),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  onPressed: handleSignIn,
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.white, //Color of the border
    style: BorderStyle.solid, //Style of the border
    width: 1, //width of the border
  ),
)
```

If I do it as mentioned below, it's effecting `FlatButton` and `RaisedButton` and this is NOT effecting `OutlineButton`.

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'MyApp',
  theme: ThemeData(
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

        // this effects to FlatButton and RaisedButton
        side: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.white, //Color of the border
          style: BorderStyle.solid, //Style of the border
          width: 1, //width of the border
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

So, How to change border **color** and **width** ONLY of `OutlineButton` globally (through out the app)?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do for that in OutlineButton. So, what i can suggest you is to create a global theme data in a global file.

```
var borderData=BorderSide(
    color: Colors.white, //Color of the border
    style: BorderStyle.solid, //Style of the border
    width: 1, //width of the border
  )
```

Then you can easily use it any class just by importing that global file.

```
OutlineButton(
  child: Text('SIGN IN'),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  onPressed: handleSignIn,
  borderSide: borderData,
)
```

This will reduce your boiler plate code in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Unless `borderSide` is explicitly added to the `OutlineButton`, it will default to a width of `1.0`, a style of `solid` and this color:

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(0.12)
```

You have the option of changing `onSurface` of your app theme, but that will affect other widgets as well.

You can do what Jay suggested in the other answer, but my preference would be to create a different widget. This way, if you ever want to change anything else to all of your OutlineButtons in the future, you only need to change your custom widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OutlineButton2 extends OutlineButton {
  const OutlineButton2({
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(
    key: key,
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: child,
    borderSide: const BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white,
      style: BorderStyle.solid,
      width: 1,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This class is deprecated, please use `OutlinedButton` instead

```
OutlinedButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: primaryColor,
        side: BorderSide(color: primaryColor),
        minimumSize: Size(200, 50),
      ),
      child: Text('SIGN IN'),
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

try deleting the `OutlineButton`

Try the code below:

```
 GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(
                              width: 2.0,
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
                    ),
                    child: Text('SIGN IN'),
                  ),
                  onTap: onPressed,
                ),
```

basically the `GestureDetector` will take the onPressed logic code and the `container` is gonna give the decoration as you ask from it with the `Text` inside